# Can I make chrome extension open as part of webpage instead of popup?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to build a Google chrome extension where I want the extension take real estate of webpage (half of browser shows webpage and half as chrome extension) instead of showing up as a popup? Is this possible or can I use Javascript injection to achieve this?

Comment: If you decide to make that by "injecting" with `iframe`, you might get into few restrictions _aka_ 'cross-domain' problem. Otherwise, I don't know the ways of doing that without creating the popup on the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible but off course you will have to face some limitations and restrictions. There is a working example implemented with same idea. You can play around with this nice example and can learn it easily.

Check this [Github](https://github.com/ffto/iHeart-Chrome-Extension).

Comment: Awesome, this is what I was looking for.